# Accessing secure Geoserver layer with username password

Tags: geoserver, layers, security, authentication

I've created Users, Groups and Roles in Geoserver. And I set the user roles for my workspace.

- user1 can read
- user2 can write

[image]

And I want to access my layers as anonymous like this:

`http:localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities`

This request returns 404 not found page.

I am using username password parameters but not working.

`http:localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities&user=some&password=some`

If I login Geoserver admin panel and layer preview, I am accessing layer. If I logout, can not.

Comment: As Francisco pointed out, that isn't the right syntax. Can I ask what you looked at to try to get the user and password syntax, especially if something suggested passing them as parameters? I'd like to update the docs to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

There is typo in your url

```
http:localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities
```

should be

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities
```

You can use basic auth to make the requests:

```
http://user:password@localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities
```

Comment: hi Francisco - on the same note if password is encrypted or digested authentication is used what will be the format of service call?.- Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can use the same schema `http://user:password@localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities` but using the encrypted password instead of the Base64 encoded that is used in basic auth