# Openlayers 3 getting 401 error from geoserver with secured layers

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, security

I have an OL3 webmap that is attempting to access services from Geoserver that is running on a server on our internal network that uses LDAP logins using windows credentials.  I found this link ([Accessing secure Geoserver layer with username password](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120077/accessing-secure-geoserver-layer-with-username-password)) and this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950747/authenticate-in-geoserver-with-asp-net-and-iis/13123640#13123640) and tried both but it is not resolving the 401 error issue.

This is the code I have from the second link:

```
//login function
function login (options) {
// url del servlet del geoserver
var url = options.server + "/geoserver/j_spring_security_check";
// parametros para el login
params = "username=" + options["user"] + "&password="
            + options["password"];

var contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
//se inicializa la petición ajax
var ajax = $.ajax({
    data : params,
    type : "POST",
    contentType : contentType,
    url : url
});
// se ejecuta cuando la peticion finaliza
ajax.done(function() {

    if ($.cookie("JSESSIONID") != null && options && options.success) {
        options.success();
    }
});
// si ocurrio un error al realizar la peticion
ajax.fail(function(data) {
    if (options && options.failure) {
        options.failure(data);
    }
});
// se ejecuta siempre al final de la petición, sin importar que esta
// haya fallado
ajax.always(function() {
    if (options && options.always) {
        options.always();
    }
});
};
var un = prompt("enter your username","");
var pw = prompt("enter your password","");
login({
    user: un, //geoserver user  
    password: pw, 
    server : "http://(host server here):8080", //geoserver host
    success : function(){
        alert("Login OK!");
    },
    failure : function(){
        alert("Login fail!");
    }
});
```

Also, if I log into the geoserver admin webpage in a separate tab, I can then open the webmapping application with no issue.  I would like to ideally remove this step by putting in the geoserver login into the actual webpage (and preferably not store the login credentials anywhere for security purposes).

Comment: What kind of services? WMS/WFS?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familar with GeoServer, but [I found this](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/auth/owsrest.html).

More generally spoken: HTTP-Status 401 means, that the server which receives your request is secured by "Basic Authentication" (hopefully via HTTPS).
You have to put the credentials in the HTTP-Request Header "authorization" (this term is a bit misleading).

The content of header "authorization" looks like
`Basic dXNlcjAxOnRvcFNlY3JldA==`
The second word is the Base64 encoded presentation of `user01:topSecret` , with ':' as separator between username and password.