# GeoServer authentication key not working as expected

Tags: geoserver, authentication, security

I'd like to secure access to my layers published on GeoServer 2.21.1. running on Apache Tomcat Version 9.0.65.

### What I want

My goal is to create a user who is the only one who can read the layers of a specified workspace.
To do this, I've tried without success all three methods explained here https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html#authkey which are *Key provider using user properties*, *Key provider using a property file* and *Key provider using an external web service*. I prefer to use a property file, so I'll continue to explain what I've done with this method, but if anyone knows how I can get the desired result with another method, I'll be interested.

### What I did

I installed the **Key authentication extension** corresponding to my version of GeoServer here: https://geoserver.org/release/2.21.1/

To do the following I relied on the official GeoServer documentation (https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/extensions/authkey/index.html#authkey) and on the topic [Accessing GeoServer with encrypted password?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254570/accessing-geoserver-with-encrypted-password/428855#428855).

First, I created an **XML user group service** called `testservice`, to which I added a user named `bob` and gave him a password. I assigned the role `ADMIN` to `bob`.

[image]

Under *Authentication* then *Authentication Providers* I created a **new provider** (username password), choosing `testservice` as the group.
Next, under *Authentication* then *Authentication Filters*, I created an **authentication key** as shown below.

[image]

When I clicked on the synchronize button, an `authkeys.properties` file was created with a key for my user `bob`.
In the *Data Security* tab, I created a **new rule**, indicating the desired workspace and a layer (just one to start with for testing purposes), selecting `read` as the **access mode** and adding `admin` as the **role**.

### Result

When I'm logged in as a `bob` and go to *Layer Preview*, the desired layer is displayed as expected by clicking on *OpenLayers* next to it. But this doesn't work when I copy the link, log out and paste the link, with the key of the user `bob` added, with following format:

```
https://XXX/geoserver/workspace/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=workspace%LAYER&bbox=XXX&width=768&height=729&srs=EPSG%3A2154&format=application/openlayers&authkey=BOB'SKEY
```

This is what I get :

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc https://XXX/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
<ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
Could not find layer WORKSPACE:LAYER
</ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

The result is the same when choosing other data formats or other layers (both raster and vector) in the rule created under *Data Security*. The result is also the same if I use `admin` instead of user `bob`.

What did I do wrong? Why don't I get the expected result which is to access the chosen layer using the authentication key?

Comment: try using `plaintext` as the "encryption" method to start out so you can see if the key is correct

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing, I used the `default` User/Group Service, as I don't necessarily need to create a new one. I finally figured out what the problem was. Turns out I hadn't done the following:

1. Under *Services*, I had to **add a new rule** where `service` is * and
   `method` is * with roles `ROLE_AUTHENTICATED` and `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` selected.
2. Then under *Authentication*, I had to modify the `default` **filter chain** by checking "Allow creation of an HTTP session for storing the authentication token" and selecting the `authkey` role.

Applying the same procedure to another User/Group Service should also work.